# if value is null should not call $group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

if $props does not exists it should return blank array instead null value how can we fix it

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$prop3"
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/3XGkbBKbtwW

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the input documents and the expected output?

Comment: please check the fiddle $prop3 does not have value it should return [] insread [
  {
    "_id": null
  }
]

Comment: From the marked answer in the duplicate `db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{prop3:{$exists:true,$ne:null}}},{$group:{_id:'$prop3'}}])` [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X5xX0VqONq3)